# Atomic design in vue 3 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm currently trying to use atomic design in my vue app.

Below is the code for my button atom:

```
<template>
  <ElButton
    :type="button?.type"
    :plain="button?.plain"
    :rounded="button?.rounded"
    :icon="button?.icon"
    :disabled="button?.disabled"
    :loading="button?.loading"
    :size="button?.size"
  >
    {{ button?.label }}
  </ElButton>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { ElButton } from "element-plus"
  import { PropType, defineComponent } from "vue"
  interface IButton {
    label: String
    type: String
    plain?: boolean
    rounded?: boolean
    icon?: String
    disabled?: boolean
    loading?: boolean
    size?: String
    rest?: any
  }
  export default defineComponent({
    name: "Button",
    props: {
      button: Object as PropType<IButton>,
    },
    components: {
      ElButton,
    },
  })
</script>
```

And i'm using the button in my `HelloWorld.vue`

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {defineComponent } from "vue"
  import Button from "./atom/input/index.vue"

  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      Button,
    },
  })
</script>

<template>
  <Button type="success" size="large" label="Primary Button" />
</template>
```

With the above setup, I can use my button component with ease. Only issue is that the button doesn't show it's text.

Though I have passed label prop to the component it is shown as attribute of the button when I inspect the button element.

Like this:

`<button class="el-button el-button--success el-button--large" type="button" label="Primary Button"></button>`

Can anyone help me to figure out what I'm missing here ?

Comment: this in not composition API, this is options API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep diving into vue typescript docs. I found the suitable solution for using interface on props with vue 3 typescript composition api.

atom/button/index.vue

```
<template>
  <ElButton
    :type="type"
    :plain="plain"
    :round="round"
    :icon="icon"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :loading="loading"
    :size="size"
  >
    {{ label }}
  </ElButton>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ElButton } from "element-plus"
  interface IButton {
    type: string
    label: string
    plain?: boolean
    round?: boolean
    icon?: string
    disabled?: boolean
    loading?: boolean
    size?: string
  }
  const { type, label, plain, round, icon, disabled, loading, size } =
    defineProps<IButton>()

</script>
```

/component/HelloWorld.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import Button from "./atom/button/index.vue"
  import Input from "./atom/input/index.vue"

  const buttonClick = (type: string): void => {
    console.log(`string text ${type} string text`)
  }
</script>

<template>
  <Button
    :type="'success'"
    :label="'Success'"
    @click="buttonClick('Success')"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your props are
`props: { button: {label: string} }`
but you are trying to use them as
`props: { label: string }`

Either

```
  <Button :button="{type:'success', size:'large', label:'Primary Button'}" />
```

or make the props correct

Comment: Is there any way where I can use these props directly like in react ? 

I'm from react background so I'm having hard time understanding vue 3

Comment: As I've said, you have *one* prop named `button`. You need multiple props.

Comment: By the way, are you new to Vue? Do you want to find a good template using all the latest features of Vue and surroinding things?

Comment: Then try https://github.com/antfu/vitesse , it uses everything you would need for a proper frontend